# React Hooks with React Router - how do I redirect to another route?

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I have a simple react hooks application - a list of Todos - with React Router v4.

On the List of Todos, when a Todo is clicked I need to:

- Dispatch the current todo in context
- Redirect to another route (from `/todos` to `/todos/:id`)

In the previous React Class based implementation I could use `this.context.history.push` to redirect to another route.

How would I handle that using React Hooks in combination of React Router v4 (in code below see my comment in function `editRow()`)?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to do is to use the useHistory hook in react

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default const App = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleRedirect = () => {
        history.push('/auth/login')
    }
    return (
<button onClick={handleRedirect}>login</button>
)
};
```